# PHP: Selecting a Table Row via JQuery

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I've been trying to test if my JQuery works by changing the color of the selected row.
What I'm aiming at is to get the data from the database, use for loop to pin the data to the table and then choose each individually, with my code; whenever I press on the rows they don't get a highlight, which means the script is not working, my code looks like the following:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

    <head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
    #HighLight {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #HighLight tr:hover {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
    tr {
      cursor: pointer
    }
    th {
      background-color: #000;
      color: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #fff !important;
      cursor: default;
    }
    td,
    th {
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      white-space: nowrap;
      vertical-align: text-top;
      overflow-x: auto;
      max-width: 250px;
      max-height: 25px;
    }
    .selected {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important;
      color: #fff !important;
    }
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>

    <script>
    $("#HighLight tr").click(function() {
      $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    });
    </script>

    <table class="Tab" id="HighLight">
    <tr>
        <th class="cell">ID</th>
        <th class="cell">Number</th>
        <th class="cell">Data1</th>
        <th class="cell">Data2</th>
        <th class="cell">Data3</th>
        <th class="cell">Data4</th>
        <th class="cell">Data5</th>
        <th class="cell">Data6</th>

    <tbody>
    @foreach ($all_users as $a)
    <tr>
    <td>{{ $a->ID }}</td>
    <td>{{ $a->Number }}</td>
    <td>{{ $a->DBData1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ $a->DBData2 }}</td>
    <td>{{ $a->DBData3 }}</td>
    <td>{{ $a->DBData4 }}</td>
    <td>{{ $a->DBData5 }}</td>
    <td>{{ $a->DBData6 }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>

    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: Working code here: https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/32jswq0g/38/

```js
$("#highLight tr th").click(function() {
  $("#highLight tr th").removeClass('selected')
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
     $(this).removeClass('selected')
   } else {
     $(this).addClass('selected')
  }
});
```

```css
#HighLight {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #HighLight tr:hover {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
    tr {
      cursor: pointer
    }
    th {
      background-color: #000;
      color: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #fff !important;
      cursor: default;
    }
    td,
    th {
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      white-space: nowrap;
      vertical-align: text-top;
      overflow-x: auto;
      max-width: 250px;
      max-height: 25px;
    }
    .selected {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important;
      color: #fff !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tab" id="highLight">
    <tr>
        <th class="cell">ID</th>
        <th class="cell">Number</th>
        <th class="cell">Data1</th>
        <th class="cell">Data2</th>
        <th class="cell">Data3</th>
        <th class="cell">Data4</th>
        <th class="cell">Data5</th>
        <th class="cell">Data6</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```